# Applying the Mean Value Theorem to conclude a function has a zero

Tags: calculus, derivatives, rolles-theorem

> Consider the function $f$ given by $f(x)=(x-2)^4\cos(x^2-4x+4)$. Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $f'$ has a zero on the interval on $[1,3]$.

I notice that to do this we must show $f'(c)=0$ where $c$ is real number in the interval $[1,3]$. Now by the Mean Value Theorem,

$$\frac{f(3)-f(1)}{3-1} =f'(c)\,.$$

Notice that $f'(c)$ is indeed $0$ on the left hand side.

Comment: A zero in what interval?

Comment: Sorry [1,3] I forgot to state in question.

Comment: I think you have to be a little crazy to use the MVT to show that that function has a zero in that interval, when there's a much much much easier way!

Comment: Do you see $x=2$ gives you zero?

Comment: I could have done that or used IVT? But the question explicitly states to use it.

Comment: For both $x = 1$ and $x = 3$, what does $(x-2)^4$ equal? What does $\cos(x^2 - 4x + 4) \ = \ \cos([x-2]^2)$ equal?  What can you conclude about $f'(c)$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not write the question properly. Apologies, it's to show f' has a zero in the interval.

Comment: So you _do_ want the MVT.  What does you find for $f(1)$ and $f(3)$ from the above?

Comment: Oops thanks haha, I mis calculated. We get f'(c)=0. Thanks for that Reckless.

Comment: Question is solved. Thanks to all above!

Comment: It's still crazy to use MVT. $f'$ is of the form $(x-2)^3g$, and $g(2)$ is finite, so $f'(2)=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed. Or simply the fact that $t\mapsto f(2+t)$ is even (and differentiable).

Answer (score 2):

First note that $x^2-4x+4 = (x-2)^2.$

Then the left-hand side of your MVT equation gives

\begin{align}
\frac{f(3) - f(1)}{3-1} &= \frac{(3-2)^4 \cos (3-2)^2 - (1-2)^4 \cos (1-2)^2}{2} \\
&= \frac{(1)^4 \cos (1)^2 - (-1)^4 \cos (-1)^2}{2} \\
&= \frac{\cos(1) - \cos(1)}{2} \\
&= 0,
\end{align}

which equals $f'(c)$ for some $c \in (1,3).$

(Notice that my interval is open.  I think this is what you intended to type.)

Answer (score 1):

First we get $f'(x)=4(x-2)^3\cos(x-2)^2-2(x-2)^5\sin(x-2)^2$, 
then we find that $f'(1)<0$ and $f'(3)>0$, so there exists $c\in[1,3]$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

The theorem I'm using here is is that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f(a)<0$, and $f(b)>0$ then there exists some $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Is this from mean value theorem?

Comment: Not really, this is what is called the Intermediate Value Theorem. [The MVT is different.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)